# Android Write File Name Formatting

Tags: android, csv

I'm currently using csvwriter/filewriter to write sensor values to a csv on the sd card, however the issue is that the file output always has Download in front of it.

How would I format with just the name, whilst still being saved in the said directory?

```
File path =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path + dateFormat.format(date)+ "GyroData.csv",true), ',');
```

The current output is Download(date)GyroData.csv , I'd like to get (date)GyroData.csv instead.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
File path =Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File(path, dateFormat.format(date)+ "GyroData.csv"), true), ',');
```

Comment: Hi , it says cannot resolve constructor.
Any ideas?
Sorry I'm still new to java.

Comment: Edited my response, had a bracket in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append the date and time in front of every recording's name first include:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

and then use:

```
String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()); 

writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(path + dateTime + "GyroData.csv",true), ',');
```